# Basket contact isn't restarting

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to make a game called Egg Catcher currently, for personal reasons (just for fun) and I'm a little bit stuck on my code. I want my egg to reset each time it either gets caught by the basket or it reaches the bottom, but it only checks for contact once and then it stops checking.. Please help.

```
import pygame
import random
caught_egg = False
a = 0
egg_radius = 15
x_egg = 0
y_egg = 5 + egg_radius
x_star = []
y_star = []
x_pos = 200
y_pos = 650
x_speed = 5
x_size = 100
y_size = 70
red = [255, 0, 0]
white = [255, 255, 255]
black = [0,0,0]
yellow = [255, 255, 0]
cyan = [0, 255, 255]
magenta = [255, 0, 255]
beige = [245,245,220]
wheat = [245,222,179]
egg_color_choices = [beige,wheat]

WINDOW_HEIGHT = 800
WINDOW_WIDTH = 500
pygame.init() # initializes the graphics module
window = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOW_WIDTH,WINDOW_HEIGHT)) # define window size
pygame.display.set_caption('Egg Catcher') # title of program that
# appears on window
# frame
def InitSky(amount):
    for i in range (0, amount):
                x_star.append(random.randint(2, 495))
                y_star.append(random.randint(2, 795))

def DrawSky(amount):
    for i in range(0, amount):
        pygame.draw.circle(window, white, (x_star[i], y_star[i]), 2, )
        y_star[i] = y_star[i] + 1
        if y_star[i] > WINDOW_HEIGHT:
            y_star[i] = 0
def InitEgg():
    x_egg = random.randint(1 + egg_radius, WINDOW_WIDTH - egg_radius)
    return(x_egg)

def EggColor():
    egg_color = random.choice(egg_color_choices)
    return(egg_color)
def DrawEgg():
    pygame.draw.circle(window, egg_color, (x_egg, y_egg), egg_radius,)
x_egg = InitEgg()
egg_color = EggColor()
# your code that draws to the window goes here

clock = pygame.time.Clock() # used to track time within the game (FPS)
quit = False
pygame.key.set_repeat(1)
while not quit: # main program loop
    for event in pygame.event.get(): # check if there were any events
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: # check if user clicked the upper
            quit = True # right quit button
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_pos = x_pos + x_speed
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x_pos = x_pos - x_speed
            if x_pos <= 0:
                x_pos = x_pos + x_speed
            if x_pos + x_size >= 500:
                x_pos = x_pos - x_speed
            if event.key == pygame.K_KP_MINUS:
                x_speed = x_speed - 1
            if event.key == pygame.K_KP_PLUS:
                x_speed = x_speed + 1
            if x_speed >= 8:
                x_speed = x_speed - 1
            if x_speed <= 4:
                x_speed = x_speed + 1



    window.fill(black)
    InitSky(500)
    DrawSky(500)

    caught_egg = False
    if caught_egg == False:
        DrawEgg()
    if y_egg - egg_radius <= WINDOW_HEIGHT and caught_egg == False:
        y_egg = y_egg + 3
    else:
        y_egg = 0
        x_egg = InitEgg()
    if x_egg + egg_radius > x_pos and x_egg  + egg_radius < x_pos + x_size and y_egg - egg_radius == y_pos:
        caught_egg = True
        y_egg = 0
        x_egg = InitEgg()
        print(y_egg)
    pygame.draw.rect(window, magenta, (x_pos, y_pos, x_size, y_size))
    pygame.display.update() # refresh your display
    clock.tick(60) # wait a certain amount of time that
# ensures a frame rate of 60 fps

pygame.quit() # shutdown module
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of this condition: `y_egg - egg_radius == y_pos`.  You start from 20 the first time (`5 + egg_radius`) so when you hit 665 that condition triggers.  But then you reset `y_egg` to 0 instead of 20 so you never align on the exact condition again.

You could just replace the two `y_egg = 0` resets by `y_egg = 5 + egg_radius`, but a better fix would be to detect if the egg geometry is contained in the bucket in the y-dimension as you do for the x:

```
if x_egg + egg_radius > x_pos and \
   x_egg  + egg_radius < x_pos + x_size and \
   y_egg - egg_radius >= y_pos and \
   y_egg + egg_radius <= y_pos + y_size:
    caught_egg = True
    y_egg = 0
    x_egg = InitEgg()
```

Actually your x logic is only checking if the right edge is inside the bucket but I'll leave that for you to fix.

Comment: Thank you very much, after about an hour of changing the code I accidentally stumbled upon that detail. I appreciate you taking your time to answer, to update if you're interested I got a scoring system and a combo system done after. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it.  If this answer helped you, please consider marking it accepted.  Welcome to SO.